# component of a divisor is mobile

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If D is a mobile divisor, why there exists a divisor $D'\in |D|$, such that any component of $D'$ is mobile? Somebody told me that it follows from Bertini Theorem. Can anybody give me some details?

Comment: If you work over a curve, this is in general false, since the components are single points which rarely move. In higher dimension, this is still false, since $D$ may have fixed components, which will appear in $D'$ and will not move. If $D$ is without fixed components (still with dimension of the variety greater than one), what you say is indeed true.

Comment: Since D is a mobile divisor, D does not have any fixed components. Could you please show me why in this case, the conclusion is true?

Comment: What exactly is your definition of a mobile divisor? I assumed that it meant that the divisor moves.

Comment: The same definition with you. But I am still not clear with your explanation. Here any component of $D′$ I mean a prime divisor in the support of $D'$.

Comment: So, why should a mobile divisor have no fixed components?  For example, let $X$ be the blow up of a point in $\mathbb{P}^2$, $E$ the exceptional divisor and let $H$ be the pull back of the hyperplane. Then $H+nE$ is mobile, since $H$ moves. But, $E$ is a fixed component if $n>0$.

Comment: Ok. Maybe our definition is different. By mobile I mean that the set of fixed divisor $F$ of |D| is empty.